# Operation Failed when burning on Astroburn Lite

Tags: dvd, iso-image, burning

I was trying to burn my windows 8 (legit) iso file to my DVD - RW because my Original DVD was lost. and i don't know where to find it. I usually use Astroburner to burn an ISO file to my DVD. When i burn it, it always said "Operation Failed". I never experienced with this problem before.

Why is that happening?

My DVD ROM : MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8D2Q

NB : i've tried Nero Burning ROM Trial but it "Canceled by user". Here's the log file

```
8056-208A-4X1C-0TC7-C7K2-AKW0-****-****

Windows 8 6.2
AMD64
Wow64Process
Nero Version: 16.0.11.0
Internal Version: 16,0,11,0

Recorder         : <MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8D2Q>      FW version: 1.10 - HA 1 TA 0 - 16.0.11.0
 Device bus      :  <>                            HA 1
 Host system bus :  <S-ATA> 
 Drive buffer    :  768kB
 Bus Type        :  via Inquiry data
CD/DVD-ROM       : <DTSOFT   BDROM           >    FW version: 1.05 - HA 1 TA 1 - 16.0.11.0
 Device bus      :  <>                            HA 1
 Host system bus :  <Virtual file backed storage bus> 

=== Scsi-Device-Map ===
                     : ATA     WDC WD5000LPVX-21A01   iaStorA Port 0 ID 0  DMA: Off
                     : MATSHITADVD-RAM UJ8D2Q  1.10   iaStorA Port 0 ID 0  DMA: Off

=== CDRom-Device-Map ===
MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8D2Q    I:   CdRom0
DTSOFT BDROM               D:   CdRom1
HTC Android Phone          K:   CdRom2
=======================

AutoRun : 1
Excluded drive IDs: 
WriteBufferSize: 83886080 (0) Byte
BUFE           : 0
Physical memory     : 3978MB (4073648kB)
Free physical memory: 1304MB (1336016kB)
Memory in use       : 67 %
Uncached PFiles: 0x0
Global Bus Type: default (0)
Check supported media : Disabled (0) 

7.11.2014
Burn DVD Image
17:54:55    #1 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 617
    LockMCN - completed sucessfully for IOCTL_STORAGE_MCN_CONTROL

17:54:57    #2 Text 0 File Burncd.cpp, Line 8524
    Burning limited to 100 MB due to license limitation. Trying to burn 4366 MB.

17:54:57    #3 PHASE 40 File dlgbrnst.cpp, Line 2088
    Canceled by user

17:54:57    #4 Text 0 File SCSIPTICommands.cpp, Line 617
    UnLockMCN - completed sucessfully for IOCTL_STORAGE_MCN_CONTROL
```

Comment: "Burning limited to 100 MB due to license limitation. Trying to burn 4366 MB."

Comment: What is that mean?

Comment: Means exactly what it says. You're using a trial version; it will stop when it reaches 100MB

Comment: So i have to buy the full version of nero burner? if yes, is there any free software to burn without limitation?

Comment: or find the log from astroburner, to see where/why it failed.

Comment: Only Failed to send OPC